# Certain computer doesn't boot from external hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I've installed ubuntu on the external hard drive. (Toshiba HDD from Apple Mac Pro. 500 GB. I use HDD enclosure)  I've tried to run it on different machines at my work. It works fine on most of the machines. But, I can't get it to boot on certain type of machines with the following specs:

- HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF
- Intel i3-4130 3.4 GHz
- 4096 MB
- BIOS: L01 v02.21 12/17/2013

Some time ago, I installed Linux Mint on flash drive and it worked just fine on these machines.

These machines will boot with installation USB stick.

I've tried to install Ubuntu on the same hard drive using this type of machine in legacy and UFI mode. Neither worked.

When I try legacy it installs fine and then doesn't boot. When I try UFI it produces error: "Failed to install grub-efi to /target/ the system will not boot"

When I removed internal HDD and put external HDD without the enclosure it did boot in legacy mode. But I want it to boot as external drive.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relatively easy solutions that are likely to work, although neither is certain to work:

- Boot from an emergency Ubuntu disk and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. This tool will re-install GRUB (Ubuntu's boot loader) on the computer. Note that Boot Repair will try to install in the boot mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy or EFI/UEFI) used to boot the emergency disk you used. If you've got another OS with which you're dual-booting, it's imperative that the two boot modes match. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject. (That page is written with the assumption that there's an existing Windows EFI-mode installation, but of course it could be the other way around.)
- Use the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) to boot Ubuntu, then install rEFInd via its PPA or Debian package. This approach should work well if the disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and has an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) These conditions should be true if you installed in EFI mode, but may not be true if your original install was in BIOS mode, or if you tried to do an EFI-mode install to a disk that already used the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system.

If you continue to have problems, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (or post the URL provided by Boot Repair when you run it). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration.